# Codename One, Possible to access photos without using Display.getInstance().openGallery()?

Tags: codenameone

Is there are way for codenameone apps to access the images stored on the device programmatically and not using Display.getInstance().openGallery().

I want to construct my own gui for selecting images.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

No. You can access these files as read only in a device specific way using native interfaces. Historically this wasn't possible technically in iOS and it was only possible to launch a picker UI to view the content of the camera roll.

For iOS the Photo's native API can be used https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos?language=objc

It would require wrapping that with a native interface which is non-trivial https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html

Comment: Thx for the reply. Just to be absolutely sure before I go down the native route...I only require the full paths of any jpegs on the file system. I would then load them in turn.

Could I use the "directory walker" in :

https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/FileSystemStorage.html

To get the names of the images on both android and ios without any issues and without having to go native ? Many Thx

Comment: I don't know. I haven't used these API's as they didn't exist when we created the gallery API. I'm not sure if you will get a path to a file since there are security implications in the native code.

Comment: Without any native code : I managed to display images from the users existing photo gallery on Android but on iOS I can only seem to access directories available to my CN1 app and hence not the users exisiting photo gallery. Am I possibly missing any iOS permission build hints etc ? I suspect iOS security is preventing me :-(

Comment: iOS sandboxes apps more rigorously than Android. You will need the API usage and the permission. I doubt you'll be able to access photos without both.